# How do we use "drill in"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, idiomatic-language

I found an entry in a dictionary, but it only says "teach by drills and repetition" without providing any example. Now, my question is if we can say "drill yourself in X".

For example:

> You can drill yourself in advanced dribbling skills by practicing with
>   our dribbling coach during the team drills.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You *can* say "drill yourself in" like you did in the sentence. However inserting "[someone]" between "drill in" does not always preserve the meaning of the sentence.

---

Part of the confusion comes from two ways "drill" can be used. Either referring to the power tool or referring to a kind of practice. See [Cambridge's](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drill) first two definitions:

> 1. a tool or machine that makes holes
> 2. an activity that practises a particular skill and often involves repeating the same thing several times, especially a military exercise intended to train soldiers:

The trouble comes in when determining if the phrase "drill in" is being used as a verb phrase metaphorically, or if the "in" is a preposition and not part of the verb phrase.

"drill in" *can* be used metaphorically, similar to "beat in" or "hammer in". Although the more common phrasing is using "into" instead of "in".

> Those pop-quizzes really [drilled in]/[hammered in] the importance of studying every night.

It can *also* be used in other circumstances to refer quite literally to routine practice, similar (but more specific) than the verb "test"

> The daily quizzes we took, meant we were drilled in Supreme Court cases every day.

Therefore it is important to determine which sense is being used before transforming it into "drill [someone] in", so that the meaning is not changed.

---

> [something/someone] drilled [something] in/into [someone]
>
> > nearly always in the "beat in"/"hammer in" sense
> >
> > He drilled the parts of the cell in us
>
> [something/someone] drilled [someone] in/on [something]
>
> > nearly always in the more literal "practice" sense.
> >
> > He drilled us in the parts of a cell
>
> [something/someone] drill in [something]
>
> > sort of ambiguous and can depend of the context
> >
> > We drilled in the parts of the cell.

---

An interesting example is :

> Reviewing my flashcards helped me drill in those organic reactions.

Here,I would take this to mean the metaphorical sense similar to "hammer in. **in** is being used as a preposition to indicate "where" the drilling is going. (usually into someones mind/brain). "drill in" here means to semi-permanently fix some information in your brain by rote memorization, as if you drilled a hole into your brain and placed the information there. The sentence would usually be parsed as:

> [Reviewing my flashcards helped me drill in] (those organic reactions).

However one could also take it to mean "drill" as in the route practice, the usage here is kind of ambiguous.

**However** If the sentence were changed to:

> Reviewing my flashcards helped me drill myself in those organic reactions.

This sentence makes sense but "drilled" is no longer being used metaphorically to refer to the power tool. Instead is describing the type of practice as a "drill" similar to a military drill.

---

In your example, and most usages of "drill yourself in" that I can think of (at least when it means to practice) the **in** takes a different usage.

> You can drill yourself in advanced dribbling skills.

Here the **in** is part of the phrase "in advanced dribbling skills" rather than "drill in". The **in** here is used to specify the **topic** as opposed to making a compound verb phrase. This sentence would be parsed as

> [You can drill yourself] (in advanced dribbling skills)

Comment: In both cases, what follows min is the subject or skill being drilled: dribbling or organic reactions.  It has nothing to do with placing the information in the brain by  figurative use of a drill. Rather, in both "drill in" and 'drill yourself in" the metaphor is routine military practice in marching and other repeated actions, known as "drill" "loading drill" "saluting drill" and the like.

Comment: I kindly disagree, If the verb the usage changes the verb phrase from "drill in" to just "drill" with a preposition "in" that changes the meaning. Looking at [this definition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/drill+in), one can see synonyms such as "beat in" or "hammer in". Similarly "hammer in those organic reactions" does not mean the same as "hammer yourself in those organic reactions".

Comment: While "hammer in"  does mean much the same as "drill in" it comes from a different metaphor, and the linked definition is **wrong** to use it as it does. One hammers procedures into the recruits, but one drills the recruits in procedures.

Comment: I would say to drill [something] **into** [someone] [link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drill%20into) is acceptable. I think the confusion come in as to whether "drill" is referring to metaphorically using the **power tool**, or referring literally to routine practices.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drill gives: "drill pupils in spelling"; https://www.dictionary.com/browse/drill gives: "to go through exercise in military or other training." https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drill+in has "Now, I am going to drill you in irregular verbs.";  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/drill gives "He drilled the children in what they should say."

Comment: Yes, the metaphor of the power drill is possible, but I don't think is what is being used in the examples here, rather literal practice, derived by extension from military drill. To drill something into someone is not the same as to drill yourself in soemthing, nor the same as to drill someone in something. "into" evokes the power drill, i think.

Comment: I updated so that it might be more clear that there are multiple possibilities. Also the examples you gave are mostly "drill [someone] in [something]" which is different from "drill [something] in/into [someone]"

Comment: True, but the example in the question is drill {yourself} in {something}. No "into" and no person after the 'in" All the exampels of the power-drill metaphor that you cited or I found seem to use 
"drill into {something}"